# how to create java pojo

Tags: java, properties, text-parsing

I want to read a properties file and create a pojo from it. where the property key is the instance variable with getters and setters. and property value is the data type of the instance variable. input would be something like this

```
className=Temp
packageName=com.temp
name=java.lang.String
```

output would be

```
package com.temp;
import java.lang.String;
class Temp{
  private String name

  //getters and setters
}
```

what is the easiest way to do this. Should I create a file and write to it .or is there a better way.

Comment: parse the properties file, create a text file .java and write in it the parsing result.

Comment: If it doesn't need to be a properties file you may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787049/simple-code-generation

Comment: It seems like you want to create a *class*, not an object instance (as implied by the term Plain Old Java Object).

Comment: Do you want to generate the class code from the properties file or populate the values of an existing class, or both?

Comment: i want ot create a class not an instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once generated Java file using [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine) , you may want to take a look into it.

In short you template a file then use it to generate what you want.

Comment: I totally agree with this approach.  Apache Velocity seems like it would be perfect for this.  Just write the output of the template to a file.

Answer (score 1):

[Java Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) is specifically for instantiating objects on the fly. Be mindful of performance hit you take though.

> Reflection is commonly used by programs which require the ability to examine or modify the runtime behavior of applications running in the Java virtual machine. This is a relatively advanced feature and should be used only by developers who have a strong grasp of the fundamentals of the language. With that caveat in mind, reflection is a powerful technique and can enable applications to perform operations which would otherwise be impossible.

Comment: +1: Its likely the performance hit isn't as high as you might expect. i.e. a few micro-seconds.

Comment: I don't thnk this is what the OP's asking.

Comment: I guess it is ambiguous. If generating a java file from metadata, then reflection is useless.

Answer (score 1):

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try  
{
    FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter("filename.java");
    properties.load(new FileInputStream("filename.properties"));

    outFile.print("package ");
    outFile.println(properties.getProperty("packageName"));

    outFile.print("import ");
    outFile.println(properties.getProperty("name"));

    outFile.print("public class ");
    outFile.println(properties.getProperty("className"));
    outFile.println("{");
    // ... 
    outFile.println("}");

    outFile.close();
}  
catch (IOException e)  
{
    // handle the error 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check http://codemodel.java.net/ if you want to create more complex classes.